# rename Files of past two days with the there file creation time as suffix and scp the same

Tags: linux, rename, scp

I am stuck with commands in Linux where logic is below. Getting the list of files with Yesterday and they-before-yesterday with creation date and renamining them and transfer via scp.
file name should be like <<<YYYYMMDD_creation_date_of_that_filename>>>_filename.

for e.g.

1. getting output

`ls -lrth --time-style=+"%Y%m%d"  | egrep "`date -d '1 day ago' '+%Y%m%d'`|` date -d '2 day ago' '+%Y%m%d'`" > tmp.txt`

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 418K 20211225 log.897.gz
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 419K 20211225 log.898.gz
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 419K 20211225 log.899.gz
```

2. renaming. this will rename with creation time of that same file as suffix

   `for f in tmp.txt|awk '{print$7}'; do cp "$f" "$(stat -c %Y "$f" | date +%Y%m%d)_$f"; done`
3. transfer all these file in one go

`for i in list_of_file_from_above; do scp $i user@server.com:/target/folder;done`

I am stuck in somewhere loop.
also every time i have to enter password for scp
Please help.
"tar" option can also be considered.

Comment: What does `tmp.txt|awk '{print$7}'` even supposed to do.

Comment: it gives me file name log.897.gz, log.898.gz, log.899.gz. i had used as per my logic to get files names.

Comment: Well that's odd I'm pretty sure it would give you a command not found (or in the context of for a syntax) error or something.

Comment: I am getting the files name in the file and reading the same in for loop to rename them

Comment: Nope you should have gotten `bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`|'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have two questions that are critical blockers.

1. How do I filter files by date?
2. How can I use ssh without passwords?

For the first question, use find. There is a nice clue [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29245/how-to-list-files-that-were-changed-in-a-certain-range-of-time) but that doesn't quite get you to the finish line. Note that the upper bound is exclusive, so that is why I set it to the current date rather than yesterday.

```
find . -type f -newermt $(date +%Y%m%d --date "2 days ago") \! -newermt $(date +%Y%m%d)
```

For the second question, you will want to use SSH keys. The [documentation for ssh-keygen](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/keygen) has good examples and is easy to read. In brief, you will:

- Create a public/private key pair;
- Copy the public key to the server (the destination machine for your ssh command);
- and specify the location of the private key in the scp command with the -i option.

Tip: since you want to use the key in an automated application, do not enter a key password. This is a risk if your key is compromised, so be smart about it.

Comment: Thanks paul. but my question was filter files by date, rename them with their modified date and transfer them with ine single SCP. [ all three operations in one go :) ]

Comment: Hovewer I  am ecploring to use Tar but again failed.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304764

Comment: for file in \`find . -type f -newermt $(date +%Y%m%d --date "2 days ago") \! -newermt $(date +%Y%m%d)\` ; do newname=$(basename -s .gz $file)$(ls -l $file --time-style=+"%Y%m%d" | awk '{print($6)}').gz; scp $file user@server.com:/target/folder/$newname; done

Comment: thanks for the command. but it is everytime asking for password to input. is it anyway I should input the password once. for e.g.  `scp for i in list_of_file_from_above....` something like that

Comment: This is the second critical blocker I mentioned in my original reply. The ssh-keygen need be done only one time for each client/server pair. Follow those instructions, and you won't have to enter the password thereafter.